# Oracle - Foreign Key on non Unique - is materialized view the answer?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, materialized-view

we have the following table to store texts in different languages:

```
CREATE TABLE TXT 
(
  TXTID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, LANGUAGE VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) DEFAULT 'DE' NOT NULL 
, STEXT VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) 
, LTEXT VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) 
, LABELTEXT VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, CONSTRAINT TXT_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    TXTID 
  , LANGUAGE 
  )
)
```

So you can have multiple language with one txtid.
Now I want to have the TXTID as a foreign key on another table.
First I created a view with

```
select distinct txtid from txtid
```

which of course doesn't work because you can't really use the constraints on the view.
So I heard of the materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_txtid_txt 
REFRESH ON DEMAND
AS SELECT distinct txtid from txt

alter table mv_txtid_txt
add CONSTRAINT TXT_PK PRIMARY KEY (TXTID)
ENABLE
```

So far so fine, not perfect but I thought it would work... adding the foreign key to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE DATADICT
ADD CONSTRAINT DATADICT_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(TXTID)
REFERENCES mv_txtid_txt(TXTID)
ENABLE
```

But I get the:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

How to get the not unique TXT.TXTID as a foreign key? Do I really must use triggers on the tables to check the foreign key manually?

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you add DATADICT table schema?

Comment: @McNets will add that tomorrow, for now in short: normal field with **no key** on field TXTID, also fixed the error, was copying it from the wrong place, sorry

Comment: Is TXTID *unique* on DATADICT table? Even if it is not key on this table.

Comment: No, it is not unique. Multiple DATADICT Rows can have the same TXTID

Comment: What about having a `MASTER_TXT` table with unique `TXT_ID`, plus anything else that's true for all language variants of the text (perhaps a short description in the default language). `TXT` uses `TXT_ID` from `MASTER_TXT` as a foreign key, as does `DATADICT`.

Comment: You need `REFRESH ON COMMIT` for this.

Comment: @RDFozz yeah maybe that is the way to got.. adding another table :/

Comment: Besides the fact that a materialized view isn't the appropriate way to solve your problem, the query 
`SELECT distinct txtid from txt` isn't really materialized-view friendly because a fast refresh is not possible.
[About Materialized Views with Aggregates (...) 
For fast refresh to be possible, the SELECT list must contain all of the GROUP BY columns (if present), and there must be a COUNT(*) and a COUNT(column) on any aggregated columns](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8175) so better you use `select txtid, count(txtid), count(*) from txt`

Comment: You can have a foreign key to materialized view, I tried your code it works fine on Oracle 12c and 11g (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f1923/13 ) .  The only thing I changed is name of mview primary key - `TXT_PK` is already used in table `TXT` , so I guess your code fail because `..add CONSTRAINT TXT_PK PRIMARY KEY (TXTID)` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the concept identified by `TXT_ID` can be referenced by some other entity independently of the text language, then it deserves to be a separate entity represented by a separate table, as mentioned by RDFozz in a comment. Text translations will then become its children, as will `DATADICT`.

Comment: Isn't being in a view essentially a separate entity?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it is of course, but it enforces integrity in the wrong direction so to speak -- children (translations) now determine what parent should be.

Comment: Yeah i thought I can do it without adding a new table... but it seems impossbile..

Comment: With a materialized view you _are_ adding another table as well, albeit one with maintenance overhead and various restrictions.

Comment: Yeah you are right with this. I will add a "Master TXTID" Table. Thank you very much!